# Android WebView memory leak

Tags: android, android-webview

I am developing custom browser for android. When browser supports javascript, when you surf the site application gets much more Ram than  I use browser without javascript support. Please give an advise how to resolve this problem

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
 mWebView=new WebView(getApplicationContext());
            mWebContainer=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.web_container);
            mWebContainer.addView(mWebView);
            mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("");
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        }
        ........................................

     private static class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
        {

            @Override

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
            {

                 view.loadUrl(url);

                 return true;
            }
        ........................

      protected void onDestroy()
        {

            super.onDestroy();
            mWebContainer.removeAllViews();
            mWebView.destroy();
            mWebView=null;
            System.gc();
        }
```

created a simple WebView, such as a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you have any choice. Memory usage is managed by the webview widget, and so by the system.

So your app will use a lot of memory.

Comment: But why other browsers do not use so much memory?

Comment: I guess it's because they are created with NDK (http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html), which allows a lot more control over this kind of stuff.

Comment: You mean if I'm not used ndk, then my program can be closed at any time due to lack of memory?Why for what support JavaScript eats a lot of memory?

Comment: I just mean that with NDK you have a lot more control over memory usage and optimisation. Maybe it's a way to resolve your problem. Javascript is always hard to process, so it takes a lot of memory I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but simply can not believe that all pushed  Android with memory